# 14.10 Black Screen on Resume

Tags: nvidia, 14.10, dell, suspend, 15.04

I recently installed 14.10 on my dell latitude e6510. The machine is running an i5-540m, NVS3100M, Vertex turbo SSD, 6GB RAM, and an intel wifi link 5100AGN wireless card. Every few resumes from suspend, the display will turn on, although there will be only a black screen with a blinking cursor. The wireless lights do not appear, and hard drive activity light stays dark. The machine doesn't respond to any input, and can only be rebooted with a hard shutdown. Does anyone have a way to resolve this issue? I'm running the current NVIDIA drivers (I believe 340.76), although the problem has occurred on several different drivers.

EDIT: I tried the nvidia-current-updates driver on 15.04 (a fresh installation), and am experiencing the exact same issue. The change in drivers didn't solve the problem.

```
user_name@E6510-Ubuntu1410:~$ uname -a
Linux E6510-Ubuntu1410 3.16.0-34-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 10 18:02:58 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

user_name@E6510-Ubuntu1410:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
Codename:   utopic

user_name@E6510-Ubuntu1410:~$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       6097548    4516188    1581360      61824     105292    1367920
-/+ buffers/cache:    3042976    3054572
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to correct either the version 14.10 or the tag 14.04 and also include the output of `uname -a` and `lsb_release -a` and `free`

Comment: Added the requested output, fixed the tag.

Comment: I took a look at the requested solution, and the new drivers have no resolved the issue.

Comment: I get this on occasion with my (admittedly older & non-nvidia) laptop, but I can usually fix it if I change to another TTY via Ctrl+Alt+F8 and then back to the GUI via Ctrl+Alt+F7. This isn't a full solution, but it might be a workaround worth trying.

Comment: It happened on 14.10 as well, across a range of drivers. I'm currently on 340.76.